# Good practices of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for people's examples of good* practices when using Rails.

I've got a couple such as:

- `before_filter` calls go underneath the controller class name declaration, nowhere else.
- Base controllers for a namespace are named `BaseController`, not `ApplicationController`. There is, and should forever be, only one `ApplicationController`.
- `attr_*` methods are defined at the top of their respective classes.
- Model callbacks go after `attr_*` methods, or at the top of the model.
- Validations go at the top of the model, with custom validation methods being defined as `private` methods at the bottom of the file.

Now I'm not looking for Ruby's good practices, but more of a list of ones specifically in Rails. The ones listed above are just an example, not gospel.

* I didn't want to use the term "best practices", as best implies an ultimate, and in all things code people may disagree.

Comment: I think this is better off as a community wiki with a *one practice per answer* policy, so that people can vote their favorite practices up.

Comment: Use more OOP. Deviate from "Fat Model".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One practice I've found to be pretty consistent is when parentheses are appropriate. DSL class macros like validations and associations seem natural without them, whereas methods with an explicit receiver and argument(s) seem better with them.

```
has_many :users

User.find_all_by_field(my_var)
```

vs

```
has_many(:users)

User.find_all_by_field my_var
```

Answer (score 3):

1. I put `attr_accessible*` after the `has_*` declaration.
   I do remember getting errors if I did not declare them in the above order. (I'll recreate this problem tomorrow and reconfirm)

   Tried it out:

   Works:

   ```
   has_one :something
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :something
   ```

   But this throws error:
      `No association found for name 'something'. Has it been defined yet?`:

   ```
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :something
   has_one :something
   ```

   I think, the reason I get this error is because I am using `something` in a `scope` before the `has_one` call.
2. If you do `@posts.something` and get `nil` errors in a (say, index) view but you *know* the `@posts = Post.find` in the index action is working, *make doubly sure* you do not have another (most likely empty) `def index` somewhere (most likely lower down) in the controller class code!

Comment: I've never had an issue declaring protected/accessible attributes above my associations.